# Why this java application print "true"?

Tags: java

This is my first Class Hello.java

```
public class Hello {
    String name = "";
}
```

This is my second Class Test1.java

```
public class Test1 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.build(h);
        System.out.println(h.name);
    }
    void build(Hello h){
        h.name = "me";
    }
}
```

When I run Test1.java, it prints "me". I think I understand, because of "reference transfer".

This is my third Class Test2.java

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = null;
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.build(h);
        System.out.println(h == null);
    }
    void build(Hello h){
        h = new Hello();
    }
}
```

When I run Test2.java, it prints "true", why ? Is it "reference transfer" no longer? I am confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Java passes by value. Java passes references by value.

Comment: those much parentheses? fromer lisp programmer? :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you probably know, Java is call-by-value. Wenn you pass a reference, that reference gets copied. To be sure: The reference itself and *not* the reference's target gets copied.

Let's have a look at your first sample: When calling `build()`, the reference `h` will be copied. Because `h`(the copy in `build()`) does not get overwritten somewhere in `build()`, it always points to the memory location of the original `h`. So changing `h.name` affects the original `h`.

Sample 2 is different: reference `h` gets copied, too. But `h` gets overwritten in `build()`. The effect is that the original `h` and the `h` in `build()` point to different memory locations! The `h` in `build()` points to the newly generated `Hello` object, which will be garbage collected somewhen after the return of method `build()`.

Answer (score 3):

Java is always **pass by value**. When you have references, it just passes a copy of the reference pointing to the same object. In your case, you just reroute the copied reference to another object. That's why your original one is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different variables `h`. The first one is local to `main`. The second one is local to `build`.

If you rename your `build` variable to `x`, it should become obvious why `h` in `main` is not affected.

Edit:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = null;
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.build(h);
        System.out.println(((h == null)));
    }
    void build(Hello x){
        x = new Hello();
    }
}
```

Here you can see clearly, `x` starts as `null`. Then `x` becomes a new object. Then `x` dies. `h` doesn't know anything about what's going on in `x`'s life.

Answer (score 0):

`h.name = "me"` changes the object that is referenced by `h`. This change will be visible from any other place where the same object is referenced. `h = new Hello()` makes h reference another (new) object. This change only affects that particular variable h - not any other variable that previously referenced the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe this explains why: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html

Answer (score 0):

In Test1.java, when you pass `Hello` object `h` to build() method, the variable `main().h` and `build().h` are pointing to same object in memory.

i.e. `main().h = build().h => pointing same object`

But in Test2.java, even though you pass `main().h` to build() method, later on inside build method, you're repointing `build().h` to a new object. But this does not affect the `main().h`

i.e. `main().h != build().h` // they both point different objects.

that is why `main().h` still contains `null` and your program prints true.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand difference between Object and Reference.

In the first case, you are directly accessing object(memory in heap) and changing a value, where as in the second case the reference will have the new Object till the end of method. After that it will be no longer accessible.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
           String str = null;
           System.out.println(getString(str)== null);
   }

    public static String getString(String s){
            s = new String();
            return s;
    }
```

The above code will print **false**

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple:

1) You first create a variable 'h' and point it to null

2) When you come into the method "void build(Hello h)" you create a new variabel (also called 'h') which gets pointed to null (the pointer to what the variable is pointing towards is COPIED).

3) When you do 'h = new Hello()' you then change the new 'h' variable in the method to point towards a new instance of Hello (new Hello()).

The original variable called 'h' is unchanged.

Simple as pie.

Answer (score -1):

Because h is equal to null.

Comment: He's asking *why* h is equal to null, i.e. why doing `h = new Hello()` inside build does not affect the h in main.